# Issue merging videos with AVMutableComposition

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avassetexportsession, avmutablecomposition, avasset

I'm recording short video segments with an iOS device and then trying to merge multiple segments into a single larger video. Everything works fine, except in the final video, between each of the clip segments it will flash the first frame of the first clip.

For example, I want to merge clip1, clip2, clip3. The result is (clip1)->(first frame of clip1)->(clip2)->(first frame of clip1)->(clip3)

Here's the code I'm using to merge them.

```
AVMutableComposition* mainComposition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];

AVMutableCompositionTrack* compositionVideoTrack = [mainComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
AVMutableCompositionTrack* compositionAudioTrack = [mainComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

CMTime insertTime = kCMTimeZero;

for (NSURL* clip in self.sessionClips)
{
    AVURLAsset* asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:clip options:@{AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey:@YES}];

    AVAssetTrack* videoAssetTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    AVAssetTrack* audioAssetTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];

    [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration) ofTrack:videoAssetTrack atTime:insertTime error:nil];
    [compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAssetTrack.timeRange.duration) ofTrack:audioAssetTrack atTime:insertTime error:nil];

    insertTime = CMTimeAdd(insertTime, videoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration);
}

/* Export the video */
NSURL* exportURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@merged-video%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), @".mov"]];

AVAssetExportSession* exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mainComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];

[exporter setOutputURL:exportURL];
[exporter setOutputFileType:AVFileTypeMPEG4];

[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void){
    /* Finished exporting, save to photo album */
    [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:exportURL completionBlock:^(NSURL* assetURL, NSError *error) {
        if (error)
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }];

}];
```

All the video segments are recorded with an AVAssetWriter using fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie.

Edit: Also want to add, if I download the video segments and merge them with something like MP4Box on my Mac the resulting video is fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this.

My issue was I was recording the smaller clips as AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie, but then trying to export the video as AVFileTypeMPEG4. Recording the smaller clips as AVFileTypeMPEG4 fixed the issue.